# how to Parse a website that is using infinite scroll technique to display content?

Tags: php, web-scraping, infinite-scroll

How can I scrape all the data there? I am writing a php script to scrape data from a website having dynamic loader . I am using HTML Dom parser and scoopy to scrape the following website
 https://www.lyoness.com/au/search/partner/ .
I am beginner and i am not able to identify that how to parse infinite scroller.

```
<input id="btnNextPage" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%" value="Next page">
```

Comment: You'll need to debug this in your browser an figure out how and where the extraneous content is fetched from. Chances are it's often just a `$.load("url #div")` excerpt, sometimes a distinct paging address, or even JSON.

Comment: @mario how can i parse can you give me any example or reference. ?

Comment: Why don't you concretize your question with an example first?

Comment: I have added the link to the website I hope you understand my problem

Comment: Yes, and it's easy to see it loading additional resouces via Firebug or Developer Tools or Dragonfly. It polls `GET /au/search/loadpage?cp=0&area=2&st=&rz=&rzc=&f=&ft=Basic&…………` for more HTML content. Now how that URL is constructed depends on the JavaScript implementation. Asking for that is too broad. You'll have to figure this out yourself. (It's your scraping project after all.)

Comment: Can i load HTML content using this url in php e.g simple html dom parser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the link used to pull content using ajax,

```
https://www.lyoness.com/au/search/loadpage?cp=1&area=2&st=&rz=&rzc=&f=&ft=Basic&c=AU&r=12&la=en-AU&s=Default&isPreviousPageClick=false&_=
```

The cp variable is the page number you are loading. it means you can loop through all numbers if there is still content returned.

you can't access this link with php because even accessing this through a browser is not possible, i tried with ajax and it works, here is the ajax code you can type in the page console and change the cp it will print the ajax content, you can add a loop with some delay

```
$.ajax({
url:'https://www.lyoness.com/au/search/loadpage?cp=5&area=2&st=&rz=&rzc=&f=&ft=Basic&c=AU&r=12&la=en-AU&s=Default&isPreviousPageClick=false&_=',
success:function(data){
  console.log(data);
}
})
```

You can post your returned data after you scrape it using jquery (which is very easy then using php libraries) to your server with a post or get request and save to the database using some sort of API or disable the cross domain security option from your browser.

EDIT:

Here is a php code to retrieve the first page using CURL

```
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
            die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }
    $url = 'https://www.lyoness.com/au/search/loadpage?cp=1&ft=Basic&c=AU&r=12&la=en-AU&s=Default';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla-Djokage/1.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $output;
    //echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

You will need to loop through the cp variable in the url to can parse all pages and also you need to scrape the $output html to get all your variable and save them to the DB, i have tried the code and it works fine. i hope you will accept this solution

Comment: Thank you @djokage , is it possible to cal ajax through php script ? because I have to use php to implement the scraper .